# logback : SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy not deleting files with 4 digit "%i"

Tags: java, logback

We are using SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy/SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP in our product (logback 1.1.3). Here is snip from the logback configuration file :

> ```
> <appender name="SERVER_FILE"
>     class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
>     <file>${MY_LOGS}/myabc.log</file>
>     <append>true</append>
>     <!-- 
>         Roll log file on both time (per day) and size (250mb). Gzip on roll.
>     -->
>     <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
>         <!-- location and name of rolled log files -->
>         <fileNamePattern>${MY_LOGS}/myabc-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
>         <!-- keep 30 days worth of history -->
>         <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
>         <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
>             class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
>             <!-- whenever the file size reaches 250MB, roll it -->
>             <maxFileSize>250MB</maxFileSize>
>         </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
>     </rollingPolicy>
>     <encoder>
>         <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{24} [%C{1}.%M]</pattern>
>     </encoder>
> </appender>
> ```

The log files generated have the following names : myabc-2016-11-21.0.gz, myabc-2016-11-21.1.gz, myabc-2016-11-21.2.gz etc.

The problem is if a log file has extension (%i) more than 3 digits, it is not being deleted after 30 days (maxHistory). For example, myabc-2016-11-21.0.gz gets deleted after 30 days, but myabc-2016-11-21.**1000**.gz is NOT getting deleted.

Is there any other appender/configuration which I need to add to the logback configuration file to make sure files with more than 3 digit extension also gets deleted or is it a bug in logback?

[I have tried with logback 1.1.7, but that did not help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in logback. Here is the [jira](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1217) and here is the proposed fix ([PR](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/pull/338)).

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, looked to logback source code (version 1.2.3)

package - ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper

and found this line
`buf.append("(\\d{1,3})");`

so it is hardcoded to 1-3 digit integer, where 1000 exceeds this interval and new log files with index over 1000 are not replacing the old ones, but keep appending to filesystem.

Comment: Here is the bug raised : https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1217 and the fix containing the PR: https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/pull/338

Answer (score 2):

This issue already fixed in **1.3.0-alpha1**
you can check the commit here

https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/f264607fb450

they change from

```
buf.append("(\\d{1,3})");
```

to

```
buf.append("(\\d+)");
```

and the official news here
https://logback.qos.ch/news.html

> TimeBasedArchiveRemover is now able to deal with indexes over 999. This fixes LOGBACK-1175 reported by Diego Furtado who also provided the relevant PR.